# Sum of Squares without multiplication

Tags: arithmetic

I want to sum the squares for a given number N from 1 without using Multiplication. Is it possible?

Comment: Please check the documentation properly.Try `n = 10;Sum[i^2, {i, 1, n}]` or `Total@Table[i^2, {i, 1, n}]`.

Comment: n = 10; Sum[ Sum[j, {j, i}], {i, n}]

Comment: Or a nested `For` loop..

Comment: **HINT**: $$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\blacksquare & {\color{red}\blacksquare} & {\color{green}\blacksquare} & {\color{purple}\blacksquare}\\
{\color{red}\blacksquare} & {\color{red}\blacksquare} & {\color{green}\blacksquare} & {\color{purple}\blacksquare}\\
{\color{green}\blacksquare} & {\color{green}\blacksquare} & {\color{green}\blacksquare} & {\color{purple}\blacksquare}\\
{\color{purple}\blacksquare} & {\color{purple}\blacksquare} & {\color{purple}\blacksquare} & {\color{purple}\blacksquare}
\end{array}$$

Comment: @DavidCarraher sure. I was too quick. n = 10; Sum[Sum[i, {i}], {i, n}] is what I meant. BTW: doing Sum[Sum[i, {i}], {i, m}] gives (1/6)*(-1 + m)*m*(1 + m), while Sum[i^2, {i, m}] gives the correct (1/6)*m*(1 + m)*(1 + 2*m). Not sure if this is a bug or just stretching Sum too much ...

Comment: @Hmm, I just realized that `Sum[Sum[i,{i}] == Binomial[i, 2]`. Is that really what you wanted to see from the first `Sum`?

Comment: The answer to "Is it possible?" is obviously yes. Because multiplication of (positive) integers is just repeated addition.

Answer (score 9):

Someone certainly had to write this recursive one:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_Integer, y_Integer] := x + f[x, y - 1]
f[x_Integer, 0] := 0
f[x_Integer] := f[x, x] + f[x - 1]
f[0] := 0
```

Comment: +1 This is in the spirit of the modern foundations of arithmetic.

Answer (score 8):

Try this :

```
s[n_] := Total[ Range[n]^2]
```

to check how it works, e.g. :

```
s[5] // Trace
```

There is also a purely symbolic approach, e.g. :  $\quad n^2$ `~ Sum ~`$n\quad$ (see [Infix](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Infix.html) notation) :

```
(n^2) ~ Sum ~ n
```

> ```
> 1/6 (-1 + n) n (-1 + 2 n)
> ```

**Note :**  `Sum[ n^2, n]` returns the same as `Sum[ i^2, {i, n-1}]`   does, i.e. indefinite sums starts at `0`  while definite ones at `1`, e.g. :

```
Table[ Sum[ n^2,     n ], {n, 5}]
Table[ Sum[ k^2, {k, n}], {n, 5}]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 5, 14, 30}
> {1, 5, 14, 30, 55}
> ```

**Test**

We added belisarius's approach (`HarmonicNumber`) for comparison.

```
st = {  Sum[i^2, {i, 10^6}]           // AbsoluteTiming,
        s[10^6]                       // AbsoluteTiming,
       (Sum[n^2, n] /. n -> 10^6 + 1) // AbsoluteTiming,
        HarmonicNumber[ 10^6, -2]     // AbsoluteTiming  };

Last @ First @ st
Equal @@ Last /@ st
```

> ```
> 333333833333500000
> True
> ```

```
First /@ st
```

> ```
> {1.4570000, 1.0540000, 0., 0.}
> ```

**Conclusion**

[Symbolic computations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SymbolicComputation.html) are especially recommended

Answer (score 7):

Figuring out what the following snippet does is left as an exercise for the reader:

```
With[{n = 9},
 s = t = 0; j = 1;
 Do[
  t += j; s += t; j += 2,
  {n}]; s
 ]
```

Comment: I feel like browsing the wrong site ...

Answer (score 7):

A Mathematica minded answer:

```
HarmonicNumber[n, -2]
```

So:

```
Simplify[Sum[i^2, {i, n}] == HarmonicNumber[n, -2]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is `HarmonicNumber` implemented internally? You appear to presume its implementation does not involve multiplication. It's hard to see how that would be.

Comment: @whuber I doubt any Mma code is completely exempt from multiplications if you go down till machine code! Someone has to do pointer arithmetic ...

Comment: A lot of pointer arithmetic is done by adding. It is plausible that either at the p-code level or the machine level, many of the solutions offered here use no multiplication (nor anything even more complicated, like exponentiation). That's not so plausible for Harmonic number calculations :-).

Comment: @whuber You misunderstood me. There is no way to prevent multiplication. "Modern" machine addressing modes involve `base + (index * scale) + displacement` at the hardware level. See for example http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~xlanchen/cailiao/x86%20Assembly%20Programming.htm or any reference to the `lea` instruction in assembly

Comment: @whuber: from what I've seen internally, `HarmonicNumber` is converted to `PolyGamma[]`; numerically evaluating that would definitely require not a few multiplications.

Comment: @J.M. http://i.stack.imgur.com/yj4qd.png

Answer (score 7):

```
Total@Flatten[ConstantArray[#, #] & /@ Range[9]]
```

I think this exercise is somewhat of a Rorschach test… I don't know what the above says about me, though :)

Comment: What do _you_ think?

Comment: @Verde what is this, self-Rorschach? I don't think that works… “I think it says I'm handsome”

Comment: [“My shirt, boy! What do you see!?”](http://www.earthlab.net/2012/06/06/good-bye-and-thank-you-mr-bradbury/)

Answer (score 5):

## Ten ways to beat a dead horse

Sunday afternoon on an airplane without wifi and this was the problem I remembered reading at breakfast.  Forgive me for the time I had on my hands.  All because @Aky resurrected this dead horse.  (Thanks by the way.  I'm glad to have figured out the `CellularAutomaton` one, but we landed before I could come up with a good `MapAll` application.)

No speed demons here, but I assiduously avoided `Times`, sometimes `Plus`, too (notwithstanding objections that internally some arithmetic has to be occurring).

Simple:

```
ss1[n_] := Range[n] + Range[n] - 1 // Accumulate // Total

ss2[n_] := Total[# ~Table~ {#} & /@ Range[n], 2]
```

`CellularAutomaton`

```
ss3[n_] := 
 Total[CellularAutomaton[
    {62, {2, {{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
              {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
              {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}}, {1, 1, 1}}, 
   SparseArray[{{1, 1, 1} -> 1}, {n, n, n}], {{{n - 1}}}], 3]
```

Rules:

```
Clear[live, dead];
ss4[n_] := Length[Nest[Join[{{live, live}}, # /.
     {{live, live} -> Sequence[{live, live}, {live, dead}, {live, dead}, {dead, dead}],
      {live, dead} -> Sequence[{live, dead}, {dead, dead}]}] &, {}, n]]
```

My own `SparseArray` version:

```
ss5[n_] := SparseArray[{{i_, j_, k_} /; i <= k && j <= k -> 1},
             {n, n, n}]["NonzeroPositions"] // Length
```

Why not `LeafCount`?

```
ss6[n_] := Flatten[Table[FoldList[{#2, #1} &, 0, Range @ i], {i, n - 1}], 1] // LeafCount
```

Functional to illiterate -- I mean, illegible:

```
ss7[n_] := Total[{{#, #} &[Range /@ #], {{-#}}} & @ Range[n], 4]

ss8[n_] := NestList[Most, #, Length@#] & @ NestList[{0, 0, #1} &, 0, n - 1] //
            Flatten // Length

ss9[n_] := Fold[{#1} /. {0} -> #2 &, 0, #] & @
            FoldList[{#1} /. 0 -> #2 &, 0, NestList[{{#}} &, 0, n - 1]] /. {0} -> 0 // Depth

ss10[n_] := (x \[Function] #) /@ # & /@ (r \[Function] r[[1 ;; #]] & /@ r) @ Range @ n //
            Flatten // Length
```

**Postscript**

Got a `MapAll` one:

```
ssPS[n_] := Total @ Cases[
   MapAll[{Depth[#], #} &, #] & /@ NestList[{#} &, x, n - 1], _Integer, Infinity]
```

Comment: Actually, the thread was at the top of the list of questions and (failing to notice the date) I assumed it was a new question that had received a flurry of replies. I suppose now that was because someone had edited it. +1 for the variety.

Comment: @Aky Yeah, I didn't notice the date either.  And I didn't notice someone had edited it. +1 to you, too.

Comment: I would also like to assure all readers that no horses were harmed during the writing of these answers.

Comment: Heh, another silly one: `With[{m = 10},
 Flatten@ConstantArray[, {m, 1 + m, 1 + m + m}] ~Partition~ 6 // 
   Dimensions // First
 ]` (looks best on a mac)

Comment: @rm-rf Yeah, , right back at you, buddy!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.

Since multiplication of positive integers is repeated addition, we can repeatedly add instead of multiply:

```
n = 10;
sum = 0;
Do[
  Do[
    sum = sum + i,
    {j, 1, i}],
  {i, 1, n}];
Print[sum]
```

Answer (score 4):

An oddball one using a recursive, memoizing function for the square.

```
Clear[sq]; 
sq[n_Integer] := sq[n] = sq[n - 1] + n + (n - 1) 
sq[1] = 1;

Sum[sq[n], {n, 6}]
```

> 91

It's not something I would directly use for such a goal, but you asked for something without explicit multiplications and you got it.

Alternatively, if we don't interpret `Dot` as some kind of multiplication then

```
#.# &@Range[6]
```

would fit the requirements too.

Answer (score 3):

If exponentiation is allowed, how about this?

```
w = 10;
E^(Log[1/6] + Log[w] + Log[1 + w] + Log[1 + w + w])
```

> 385

**Explanation**

```
ClearAll[w]
Sum[i^2, {i, 1, w}]
```

> 1/6 w (1 + w) (1 + 2 w)

Answer (score 3):

**You can sum the diagonal.  However, that might be slowest procedure of all.**
[image: Times Table]

Comment: How about `Tr[t]`, assuming your table is `t`? That's what R.M. did.

Comment: @DavidCarraher, this is for others like me:  When I look at the figures, I can feel the wheels turning.
When I read the math, I find out the hamsters are dead.

Comment: Don't give up. My hamsters died a long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

I'll join the bandwagon with `SparseArray`:

```
sq[n_Integer] := Tr@SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> i^2}, n]
```

Comment: Squaring involves multiplication, doesn't it?  Tsk, tsk :-).

Comment: @whuber sshhh... it was supposed to be hidden :D Ok, you could do `{i_, i_} :> f[i, i]`, where `f` is from my [other answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10272/5) :)

Comment: Original +1 but slow `sq[10^6]; // AbsoluteTiming` yields `{2.1980000, Null}`.

Comment: @Artes Heh, of course it is slow! I thought people were generally just having fun here :) No one would really sum squares using `Tr@SparseArray...` (at least, I hope they don't and this isn't used in any decent code :P)

Answer (score 2):

A Wolfram Alpha minded answer:

```
WolframAlpha["find the sequence 1,5,14,30,55"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sos[n_Integer] := Total[Total[Range[1, #, 2]] & /@ (2 Range[n])]
```

Comment: No need to call `Total[]` twice: `Total[Range[1, #, 2] & /@ (2 Range[n]), 2]`

Comment: @J.M. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party!

```
f[n_]:=Total[Accumulate[Range[1, n + n, 2]]]
```

So for instance the first seven are

```
f/@Range[7]

{1, 5, 14, 30, 55, 91, 140}
```